# Why the graph I saved from java code is not found in the new4j DB?

Tags: neo4j

I created a graph using Java code & saved it into my neo4j db. But when I query the db through browser, I see that there is no graph. I don't see any error while executing my java code either. One issue I find is the code doesn't exit. It is just waiting forever & I had to kill it with ctrl+c.

I read records from an excel sheet & convert the data into a tree-like data-structure & save it into the DB.
I restarted the DB after running my code to see if it reloads the graph from files. But still the graph is empty.

Node Classes:

```
    package com.ptg.courseExtractor.neo4j.vo;
    import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
    import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;
    @NodeEntity
    public class CareerField extends Entity {

    String careerField;

    @Relationship(type = "CONTAINS")
    List<Strand> strands;

    public CareerField() {
    }

    public CareerField(String careerField, List<Strand> strands) {
        this.careerField = careerField;
        this.strands = strands;
    }

    public List<Strand> getStrands() {
        return strands;
    }
    }

    package com.ptg.courseExtractor.neo4j.vo;
    import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
    import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

    @NodeEntity
    public class Strand extends Entity{
    String strandId;
    String strandTitle;

    public Strand() {
    }

    public Strand(String strandId, String strandTitle) {
        this.strandId = strandId;
        this.strandTitle = strandTitle;
    }
    }
```

Code that writes the graph:

```
    val session = SessionFactory.sessionFactory.openSession()
    session.purgeDatabase()

    files.foreach(file => {
      val mappings = parseFile(file)

      val courseMaps = mappings.asScala.groupBy(x => x._1)
        .toList.map(x => new CareerField(x._1, x._2.map(y => new Strand(y._2.toString, y._3, y._4.asJava)).asJava))

      for (course <- courseMaps) {
        println(s"Saving Career Field with ${course.getStrands.size()} strands")
        session.save(course)
      }
```

Session Factory:

```
    object SessionFactory {
    val configuration = new     Configuration.Builder().uri("bolt://localhost:7687").credentials("neo4j", "*********").build();
    val sessionFactory = new SessionFactory(configuration, "com.ptg.courseExtractor.neo4j.vo")
    }
```

Console Output: (2 Graphs with 1 parent node in each & 7 and 6 children respectively.)
Saving Career Field with 7 strands
Saving Career Field with 6 strands

I queried the graph using cypher browser. I get empty output. The db is empty.
I execute the code from IntelliJ. The execution just waits indefinitely after last line in main is over. So I had to kill the execution & check the DB.
I expected the entire graph to be loaded.

Comment: For debugging purposes, I suggest to just try to insert and read back a single node

Comment: @Bajal, I tried as you said. I'm able to read the object back, but only using the same Session obj. If I close the session & open a new one to read the obj. I don't get any value back. Also, no objects are appearing the DB either.

Comment: @Bajal, There are no methods to "flush" the session either. I tried using "Transaction" to save & load. I face the same issue. I'm using neo4j desktop. Should I check anything in the settings for the desktop?

Comment: I created a node directly in the browser. I was able to fetch it into the java code. So my issue is writing a node to the DB.